# single install document for multiple Linux distributions

Tags: text, documentation

We need to distribute binaries and installation instructions for multiple Linux distributions.  Since the installation instructions are mostly similar among the distros, we would like to keep a single document that contains the common sections as well as distro-specific sections, say with special markings.  We would like to be able to run some sort of command (nroff/groff?) to generate the distro specific installation docs on demand.

What is the best way to achieve this?  I don't want to reinvent anything ...

Comment: Did you mean to tag the question with [processing](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)? That tag refers to the Processing language, designed for non-programmers to make data visualizations and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using cpp, the C pre-processor?  You can use defines to specify the distro:

```
Download the program.

#ifdef DEBIAN

Run:

sudo apt-get some_package

#endif

#ifdef REDHAT

Run:

yum install some_package

#endif
```

You can run the build on pretty much any GNU/Linux system:

```
cpp -P -DDEBIAN instructions.template
```

or:

```
cpp -P -DREDHAT instructions.template
```

Comment: thanks, a co-worker suggested m4, which I guess is in the spirit of cpp that you suggested.

Comment: @software, yeah, but `cpp` is simpler. :)

Comment: I appreciate the instructions and example.  We ought to hire you at our company!